# Cannot debug unless browsing on localhost/siteName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7

I have a couple of MVC3 web applications in my project.  I have added entries to my hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 local.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 admin.local.mysite.com
```

Both application's properties are set to use Local IIS Web server with the project URLs as follows:

```
http://localhost/mysite.web
http://localhost/mysite.web.admin
```

When I try to debug from Visual Studio, I can debug the "mysite.web" project from **both** http://localhost/mysite.web and http://local.mysite.com

For some reason, the "mysite.web.admin" project will **only** debug from http://localhost/mysite.web.admin

Any breakpoints I set will not be hit when I browse to http://admin.local.mysite.com

I dont recall doing anything different\special to allow "mysite.web" to be debuggable from other domains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I had a more detailed answer but all I can say is that after trying dozens of things found across the web, everything began working after a simple reboot.

My best guess is that the DNS resolution was cached somewhere.  I flushed my DNS, restarted IIS, restarted VS2010, etc but none of them seemed to be the issue.

I dont know where it was cached but the reboot solved it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put a Debug.Break(); in you code and see what happens. You might have to create an app pool that runs as Bryan to use this approach.
2. Why do you need to use http://admin.local.mysite.com ?
3. This is not a MVC question, there is probably lots of info if you look/ask in Web Forms.
4. Can you debug from http:///mysite.web.admin ?

Comment: 1. Nothing happens, and tried creating different app pools as you suggest too. No dice.  2. Because there are actually a handful related sites all sharing the auth cookie on the top level domain (.mysite.com) so not using that domain would cause other issues. 3.  Good point, will re-tag 4. The app that does debug correctly will do so from any domain I've tried